# Link clicks are not taking users to new webpage

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I don't know why but for some reason clicking on links does not take users to a new webpage.

This is only happening to links on a particular set of pages. I can still do a right click and open the link in new tab.

There is no error in the console so I am not sure what is going wrong. I would have posted the code but there is lot of it and no way to know what is not working or what is preventing the click from functioning properly.

Upon further inspection, it looks like the problem might be occurring because of the following code snippet:

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  // Do something
  return false;
});
```

However, I am not entirely sure about it because links on most pages are working properly even though this code is added to the common `script.js` file.

Can anyone suggest what I should do?

If this code is indeed at fault, could anyone please explain why it still allows links on some pages to work properly but not others?

Comment: Maybe just post code of a few links that don't work, the important thing is having code that reproduces the error

Comment: are the faulty link always the sames / are these link always faulty ?

Comment: Really impossible to answer the question without guessing. Could be bad mark up. It could be JavaScript code on the page that blocks clicks. Or it could be something else.....

Comment: @Luca I have updated the question after making some changes to the text. :)

Comment: @jonatjano Maybe the details I have added to the question can help?

Comment: @epascarello Could you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: so there you do, return false, cancels the click....

Comment: @epascarello then why does it still work on other pages?

Comment: well maybe the event is not there? My magic crystal ball is in the shop so I can not peer into your pages and see it. I cannot tell you why since I have zero clue what is going on other than the sparse details you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `target="_blank"` attribute to your anchor tags

For example:

From: `<a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/">somelink</a>`

To: `<a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/" target="_blank">somelink</a>`